# Why is my code executing more slowly?

Tags: windows, performance, perl, parallel-processing

In Windows, I have two separate Perl scripts: the first writes to two files while the second reads the two files and performs tasks (one such task is calling a large number of child processes that each open in a new console) according to how quickly it finds those two files updated.

The first script is set to update the files every *x* seconds (usually like 2 or 3 seconds). I record these times in a file. This works fine the first time that I run the script, and it works fine if I close all of the consoles and then restart it. However, if I leave the consoles open and start it (in one of the opened consoles), the first script takes MUCH (3 to 5 times) longer to update the files. Note that the consoles aren't executing any code, they finish their job in about 2 seconds.

I thought this was odd. It also appears that the first script doesn't slow down any more as I open more consoles, but I'm not certain of this.

Comment: Suffering from buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st comment refers to: http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html

you probably want to turn off buffering. Since you provide no code here is a small nugget to get you started.

```
$| = 1;
```